# How count the hours between two diferent formats using Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I would like to count how many hours are between this two formats using laravel query builder.. how could I do that? I would like to know if it exists a way to transform my first format which is varchar into a Timestamp format.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing `STR_TO_DATE` function to parse your format, i got the following working in MySql.

```
->select(DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, updated_at, STR_TO_DATE(fetch_tope, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s')) as hours"))
```

Comment: thanks for answer... I have this $data = DB::table('incidencias')
       ->select('incidencias.fecha_notif')
       ->get(); how could I pass fecha_notif to timestamp?

Comment: DB::Raw('STR_TO_DATE(fetch_tope, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s')') to a date but most functionality will work

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\ATC\STR_TO_DATE()

Comment: I tried with this code but didn't work... $data = DB::table('incidencias')
       ->select('incidencias.fecha_notif')
       ->select(DB::Raw(STR_TO_DATE('fecha_notif', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s')))
       ->get();

Comment: ->select('incidencias.fecha_notif', DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(fetch_tope, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s') as time")) Replace the two selects with the following

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it works!!! but It's taking 12h format... I would like 24h format.. is ti posible?

Comment: my bad %h should be %H